# How to get unallocated space info in a physical disk

Tags: c#, hard-drive

Can anybody help, how to get unallocated space information in a disk using C# ?

Comment: Define unallocated space information. Will available free space do?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know the total free space for a volume, you can use `DriveInfo.AvailableFreeSpace`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx

You can also use WMI to fetch information about partitions on the disk, using `Win32_DiskPartition` and `Win32_DiskDrive`:

Win32_DiskPartition: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394135%28VS.85%29.aspx 
Win32_DiskDrive: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

You can use the `DeviceID` field to identify which partition is on which disk, then use the `StartOffset` and `Size` fields to build a map of where the parititions are on the physical disk. Then just use the data from `Win32_DiskDrive` to work out the whole disk size, and compute the remainder.

Here's an article on MSDN that should give you all the help you need in using WMI:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257338.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System;
namespace DriveInfoExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Check only for fixed drives
            foreach (var di in DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(d=>d.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Free space on drive {0}\t{1} bytes", di.Name, di.AvailableFreeSpace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```